# Custom Facebook comment box

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

I want to build custom Facebook comments box for that I have done lots of R&D but I am stuck on how will I post comments against the url of different pages of my website.

I want the similar functionality which Facebook's comment box plugin provides like I will drop my custom Facebook comments box on my page template and it will work for all the pages which are inheriting from that template. Which means each dynamic page will have its own commenting box depending on its url.

It would be better if anyone provide me steps to achieve this functionality. I have gone through the Facebook developers forum and have learn commenting against the ID of Objects but I want to start comment box from page Url as Facebook's comments box takes href of the page.

**My test work:**

When I have posted comments through Facebook comment box plugin against url and get all of them using Graph api so all comments are listing successfully.

but when I try to post the comments against the mentioned url using graph api so I get the exception here.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KckTuX8DifY/UOFP_e-5ayI/AAAAAAAAAJc/e1wYHZGN9Nc/s629/Get+and+Post+Comments.png

I need answers of following questions.

How will I start commenting against page's url.

My custom commenting box template are shown below

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7iP0_Xi22zk/UOFOn_g_Q7I/AAAAAAAAAJI/FlnDhDTSyZs/s622/Custom+FB+comments+box.jpg

Thanks